# SVN to SVN synchronization - Master/Slave

Tags: svn, replication, visualsvn-server

We are planning to do the SVN to SVN synchronization (multi-site repository replication) we are using Visual SVN server Enterprise edition. And I'm trying for Master and Slave concept. If Master repository is down Slave repository is only readable. How to handle this situation ? Is there any possible way to trigger mail in case of repository is not reachable? Are is there any other solution to handle this?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "master repository is down". If you ask about disaster recovery, the disaster recovery procedure is described in the article [KB93: Performing disaster recovery for distributed VDFS repositories](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00093/). If you ask about high-availability, you could use other tools such as Windows Failover Clustering that are designed for this task.

Note that the [Multisite Repository Replication](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) feature of VisualSVN Server is driven by VisualSVN Distributed File System (VDFS) technology. VDFS is a robust and reliable technology. With VDFS you can be sure that the following statements are always true:

- *Master repository is always readable and writable — even if some of the corresponding slave repositories are unreachable*.
- *Slave repository is always writable if there is a connectivity to the corresponding master repository*
- *Replication is resilient to temporary connectivity issues*.
- *Read access to the slave repository does not require connectivity to the corresponding master repository*.
- *It is possible to recover if a master repository is lost due to disaster*.

The main failure resilience guarantee of the VDFS technology is that a master repository never depends on any of the slave repositories. As the master server never depends on any of the slave servers, you get a great level of robustness if your master server runs in a fault-tolerant environment. Even if all the slave repositories are down or unavailable, the master repository remains readable and writable. It is also guaranteed that in case of network failures, the replication will be automatically recovered after the network is restored.